# How to tell that a reciprocal relationship exists by a residual plot?

Tags: r, self-study, anova, residuals

I'm following an example from the book "R by Example", where they talk about two-way ANOVA.

The database used in `poison`. The analysis is:

```
L <- aov(Time ~ Poison * Treatment, data = poison)
```

Further on, the book says:

> The residual plots suggest a reciprocal transformation of the response
>   (poison survival time) (The dependent variable`Time`)...

That is, a more appropriate variable would be `1/Time`.

Here is the residual plot, using `plot(L)`:

[image]

I guess that the reciprocal relationship is evident by the gradually increasing residuals. Why is this correct?

When making the reciprocal model using `L <- aov(1/Time ~ Poison * Treatment, data = poison)`, the residual plot no longer has this property:

[image]

So my questions is **how could I've known that the special pattern in the first residual plot suggests a reciprocal relationship?**

Comment: Use a spread-vs.-level plot. I explain and illustrate their use at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74594/919 and you can find more about them by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=spread+level+transform). With a little practice one can eyeball a residuals vs. fitted plot and imagine the resulting spread-vs.-level plot (although many people have been fooled by the visual variation that occurs when residuals are clustered within horizontal bands).

Answer (score 2):

To address your question directly, the key is in the **increasing scatter to the right** in your first image.  This essentially showing you that as fitted values increase the spread of residuals also increase.  This means your data is heteroscedastic.   **As a rule-of-thumb, a *cone* opening to the right, you transform with a reciprocal.**  That is likely why the author states a reciprocal relationship.

That said, the comment by whuber is still very relevant and looking at spread-vs-level plots would be valuable.  Over time you become more familiar with distributions and their meanings.

Comment: This rule of thumb is too limited and would seem to contradict equally valid (and limited) rules such as to use a log transform when observing such a "cone." In fact, if the residual plot shows a *true* cone, implying the spread-vs-level plot is linear, then the log is the correct transformation to use, not the reciprocal.  The reciprocal is indicated when the spread increases *quadratically* with the level.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your additional points.  I am just posting what I have read, such as [Hair et. al.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Multivariate_Data_Analysis.html?id=JlRaAAAAYAAJ) where it states this recommendation as well. In no way do I mean to say that the user should just use the reciprocal and be done.